# Fixing Fatal Exception: main process Errors

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner to using Java and Android Studio, this code is part of a project from class for a point and click mole game. Clicking the mole a certain amount increases the level and after can be submitted as a high score. The game saves each players highscore as a generated button, the problem I'm having is the condition I have to sort the highscores by highest level reached. The LevelArray contains the the highest levels players have reached and I'm trying to get them in a condition so I can sort the generated buttons. If my idea does not work can someone offer another method for sorting these buttons? Below I included the global page I have wit`enter code here`h the page containing the loop, and included the errors I received when entering the page with the loop.

Errors

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dellstudio.projectone, PID: 20875
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dellstudio.projectone/com.example.dellstudio.projectone.page3}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at java.util.Vector.arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(Vector.java:907)
        at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:328)
        at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:442)
        at com.example.dellstudio.projectone.global.getLevelArray(global.java:56)
        at com.example.dellstudio.projectone.page3.onCreate(page3.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Page with loop condition

```
 Button hs;
int numhold=0;
String namehold ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pagethree);
    hs = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.hsReturn);
    hs.setOnClickListener(sListener);

    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay);




    global gN = (global)getApplication();



for (int i = 0; i < gN.getArray().size(); i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < gN.getArray().size() - i; j++) {
        if (gN.getLevelArray(j) < gN.getLevelArray(j + 1)) {
                   /* numhold = gN.getLevelArray(j);
                    gN.levelArray.set(j, gN.getLevelArray(j + 1));
                    gN.levelArray.set(j + 1, numhold);
                    namehold = gN.getNameArray(j);
                    gN.nameArray.set(j, gN.getNameArray(j + 1));
                    gN.nameArray.set(j + 1, namehold);
                    */
        }
    }

}


    for (int i = 0; i < gN.getArray().size(); i++) {

        Button newButton = new Button(this);
        newButton.setId(i);
        newButton.setText(gN.getNameArray(i) + "    Level: " + gN.getLevelArray(i));
        newButton.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


      //  if(gN.name.equals(gN.nameArray.get(i))) {
      //      newButton.setOnClickListener(userListener);
      //  }
        l.addView(newButton);
    }


}
```

Global

```
List<Integer> levelArray = new Vector();
List<String> nameArray = new Vector();




public String getName (){
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String s){
    this.name = s;
}

public String getPass (){
    return this.pass;
}
public void setPass(String s){
    this.pass = s;
}



public String getAge (){
    return this.age;
}
public void setAge(String s){ this.age = s;
}

public Vector getArray (){return (Vector)this.nameArray;}
public String getNameArray (int i){return this.nameArray.get(i);}
public void setNameArray(String j){this.nameArray.add(j);}

public int getLevelArray (int i){return this.levelArray.get(i);}
public void setLevelArray(int i){this.levelArray.add(i);}
```

Comment: `ComponentInfo{com.example.dellstudio.projectone/com.example.dellstudio.projectone.page3}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` this is your error.

Comment: The problem is " if (gN.getLevelArray(j) < gN.getLevelArray(j + 1)" so the second part should be fixed so that it does not look for a part of the array that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have 2 arrays but treat them as they have equal number of elements.

Perhaps the level array has less children than the name array?

Comment: The problem for now is the condition around the sort, I commented out the sort so it is not a problem yet.